# how to display the single row data form mysql database in listview of android layout?

Tags: android

I am trying to display the employee details in profile layout, I am trying to show them using the `listview` and also I try the table layout but I can display them in only in horizontal but I want them to display one by one in vertical layout. I don't know how to display them in vertical order, is there is possible solution to show them in vertical,
this is my code:

```
profile layout

    package com.example.myapplication;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        getJSON(Config_URLS.TAG_PROFILE);
    }


    private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {

        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    loadIntoListView(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    }

    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] profiledata = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            profiledata[i] = obj.getString("Profile_Data");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, profiledata);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

the above code only get the data from php file and display them in toast. I did not get any idea to show them in `listview` in vertical order. 
this is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3d455b"
    tools:context=".Profile">



    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="271dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="40dp">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="MY PROFILE"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />




            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#3d455b"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/hscrll1"
                        android:fillViewport="true"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <ListView
                                android:id="@+id/listView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </HorizontalScrollView>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my json output:

```
 {"Profile_Data":[{"StoreID":"22325","EmployeeId":"15","Cashier_name":"","Cashier_id":"0","Payroll_clockin":"","Employee_First_Name":"Damiana","Employee_Middle_Name":"","Employee_Last_Name":"Lobato","Color":null,"Sex":"male","Address":"1st","Email":"damiana_ala@hh.com","Cell":"2179356","City":"Sacramento","State":"CA","Pincode":"9999","Role":"Shiftlead","Status":"N","Basicpay":"0.00","Username":"rajesh","Password":"1995","Dateofhire":"0000-00-00","DateofTerm":null}]}
```

please anyone help me to find the solution like this output

```
StoreID: 22325
EmployeeId: 15
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Listview never put in scrollview.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3d455b"
    tools:context=".Profile">
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="271dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="40dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="MY PROFILE"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

you have to create Custom Adapter to view of item in listview.

Comment: its not working bro,i want to display them in vertical order one by one is there is any possible solution for it?without/ with using listview

Comment: split json object into single variable and then append into single string by '\n' (to break string) and put into adapter.

Comment: bro can you post any example code for it,so that i can understand.